# Decryption in android N fails

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, android-7.0-nougat

The following function is used to decrypt the encrypted content which is stored in a file. The same function generates the desired output in Android OS versions up to Nougat. In Android Nougat the decrypted file is having double the actual size, when compared to the file generated in Andorid M. Also we found that the while loop used to write data to the file is executed twice the no of times when compared to that of Android M. Please suggest a valid solution.

Already tried changing

```
byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes();
byte[] ivBytes = ivString.getBytes();
```

to

```
byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] ivBytes = ivString.getBytes("UTF-8");


public static  void  decryptPDFBook(String filePath, String key, String ivString, ShelfItem item) {

    InputStream  finStream;
    byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes();
    byte[] ivBytes = ivString.getBytes();

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
    try {
        finStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        Cipher cipherInstance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipherInstance.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParamSpec);
        CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(finStream, cipherInstance);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        String newpath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +File.separator+ "ebooks"+File.separator+"ief"+File.separator+item.getId()+"_temp.pdf";

        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +File.separator+ "ebooks"+File.separator+"ief");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newpath);

        byte[] decodedByteChunk = new byte[1024];   
        int bytesAvailable = cipherInputStream.read(decodedByteChunk);
        while (bytesAvailable != -1) {
            fos.write(decodedByteChunk);
            bytesAvailable = cipherInputStream.read(decodedByteChunk);
        }
        byteArrayOS.close();
        cipherInputStream.close();
        fos.close();

       File encryptedFile = new File(filePath);
        if(encryptedFile.exists()){
           encryptedFile.delete();
           File file = new File (newpath);
           file.renameTo(encryptedFile);
       }


    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException nspe) {
        System.out.println("Inside NoSuchPaddingException");
        //Log.d("ELSAPAC", "BookExtractionUtil decryptPDFBook NoSuchPaddingException");
        nspe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
        System.out.println("Inside NoSuchAlgorithmException");
        //Log.d("ELSAPAC", "BookExtractionUtil decryptPDFBook NoSuchAlgorithmException");
        nsae.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ike) {
        System.out.println("Inside InvalidKeyException");
        //Log.d("ELSAPAC", "BookExtractionUtil decryptPDFBook InvalidKeyException");
        ike.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException iape) {
        System.out.println("Inside InvalidAlgorithmParameterException");
        //Log.d("ELSAPAC", "BookExtractionUtil decryptPDFBook InvalidAlgorithmParameterException");
        iape.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {     
        System.out.println("Inside IOException");
        //Log.d("ELSAPAC", "BookExtractionUtil decryptPDFBook IOException");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        decryptPDFWithoutPadding( filePath,key,ivString,item);//pad block corrupted
        //return data;
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
     finally {        
    }

   // return null;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one thing that comes to mind is that you're ignoring the return value of `cipherInputStream.read()`. You just check whether any data was read, but then your write the whole `decodedByteChunk` no matter how many bytes were actually read. Try modifying your while loop like this:

```
int bytesAvailable = cipherInputStream.read(decodedByteChunk);
while (bytesAvailable != -1) {
    fos.write(decodedByteChunk, 0, bytesAvailable);
    bytesAvailable = cipherInputStream.read(decodedByteChunk);
}
```

See if that fixes your problem.

Comment: hi it actually fixed the problem. But can u please elaborate on this. Why it was required for android N and in older versions its working properly without this change.  Regards.

Comment: `InputStream.read(byte[] buffer)` doesn't have to fill the whole buffer with data. In your case `decodedByteChunk` is 1024 bytes long which means that `cipherInputStream.read(decodedByteChunk)` can read 1024 bytes **or less**. It will read less than 1024 bytes when you're at the end of the stream and there's no more bytes to read, or for any other internal reason that we know nothing about. Older Android versions probably read full 1024 bytes, whereas in Android N the implementation changed and now it reads just 512 bytes (or whatever). You must always check how many bytes were actually read.